# IQueryOver from ICriteria

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria, queryover

I have this scenario:

1. `var query = Session.QueryOver<T>()`
2. `var criteria = query.UnderlyingCriteria.SomethingThereAddCriterion()`

How can I transform criteria back to IQueryOver()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your criterias has been added to the `UnderlyingCriteria` of `query`. So you don't need to transform `criteria` to IQueryOver(). Just use `query` again.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for such quick answer :)